# How to print (access) linked lists inside of a linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Consider a linked list includes linked lists, as shown in the following code:

```
struct path {
   int node;
   struct path *next;
};

struct path_list {
   struct path *path;
   int path_size;
   struct path_list *next;
};
```

So, I define `listHead` and `listTail` for `path_list` and I am able to print and access the `path_size`:

```
struct path_list *listHead = NULL;
struct path_list *listTail = NULL;
```

but I do not know how can I access the paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your data structure is a little bit weird, as you maintain two `path_lists`, i.e. a head and a tail, whereas there should be one path_list comprising both a head and a tail.

I'd suggest to have the following data structure:

```
struct path {
   int node;
   struct path *next;
};

struct path_list {
   struct path *head;
   struct path *tail;
   int path_size;
};
```

Comment: I edited it. You are right and I have two structs.

Comment: Clear. Also think of redesigning `path_list` as suggested. Maintaining head and tail seperately is redundant and hard to use.

Comment: Is your mean just save `head` and `tail` of each list? I think I got it, but why you remove `struct path_list *next`?

Comment: a path_list maintains a series of path elements, of which `head` points to the first, and `tail` points to the  last. In between, the  path elements themselves point to the `next` path element in  the  series; a `path_list.next` pointing to another path_list very likely makes no sense, and a `path_list.next` pointing to a path makes  no sense, as `head` is already the entry point to the series.#

Comment: Ok. But I will have multiple paths and each path has some nodes. For example: path_1: `1, 2, 3`, path_2: `1, 4, 5` and ... and I want to have a list of all of them and I will be able to access them separately.